# Can anyone help me with Linq Sorting

Tags: c#, linq

There are two tables

**FeatureComparision**

```
FKFeatureId FKHandsetId Value
29           208        207MP
46           208        upto 11h
```

**Feature**

```
PKFeatureId FeatureName DisplayInOverview SortOrder
29           Focus        1                          1
46           StandBy      1                          2
//DisplayInOverview column is of type bit
```

Desired output with sql is

```
select f.featurename,fc.Value
from FeatureComparision fc
join Feature f on fc.FKFeatureId = f.PKFeatureId
Where fc.FKHandSetId = 208 and f.DisplayInOverview=1
order by f.SortOrder
```

and the linq is

```
var Specs = from fc in objCache.LstFeatureComparisions
            join f in objCache.LstFeatures
            on fc.FKFeatureId equals f.PKFeatureId
            where (fc.FKHandSetId == 208 && f.DisplayInOverview == true)
            select new
            {
             f.FeatureName,
             fc.Value
            };
```

How can I do the sort like sql in this linq

Comment: I don't see anything wrong. Are you sure you are pointing to the same DB?

Comment: Have you tried checking for `DisplayInOverview == 1`? A bit is not a boolean unless cast as such.

Comment: This is not a left join

Comment: Is that the correct SQL query? Or you need an outer join?

Comment: Sorry, My mistake with the class. I corrected it. Could you please suggest on the sort?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `orderby` string:

```
var Specs = from fc in objCache.LstFeatureComparisions
        join f in objCache.LstFeatures
        on fc.FKFeatureId equals f.PKFeatureId
        where (fc.FKHandSetId == 208 && f.DisplayInOverview)
        orderby f.SortOrder ascending
        select new
        {
         f.FeatureName,
         fc.Value
        };
```